# Using $\log$ and $\ln$ in Integration

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I found in some integral equations where they use $\log(n)$ and in some other with $\ln(n)$.

Suppose

$$ \int_{n_0}^{\large\frac{n_0}{2}} \frac{1}{n}dn $$

Which formula should I use ?

$$ \log(n)\ \mbox{or}\ \ln(n) $$

Comment: @Amzoti Sorry I couldnt get u.. Which formula should I use ?

Comment: Thank you. And let me know why do we do so ?

Comment: I didn't get anything...Could u pls explain ?

Comment: People in Engineering, and the physical sciences, still often use $\log$ to mean logarithm to the base $10$. In mathematics, $\log$ usually means logarithm to the base $e$, that is, the natural logarithm, often called $\ln$. In mathematics formulas, usually $\log$ and $\ln$ mean the same thing.

Comment: @Integrator i am sorry to say that it didn't. I am searching why should I use $In$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends who you talk to. For example, a mathematician would say that
$$ \log x = \log_e x = \ln x$$
But a computer scientist would sat that
$$ \log x = \log_{10} x $$
I avoid these issues by writing $\ln x$ for the natural logarithm. I also explicitly write the base in all other situations, for example $\log_a x$. 
As for your integral, here are the steps
$$ \int_{n_0}^{\frac{n_0}{2}} \frac{1}{n}dn = \ln \left|\frac{n_0}{2}\right|-\ln |n_0|=\ln \left|n_0\right|-\ln |2|-\ln |n_0|=-\ln 2 $$

Comment: why didn't you use $/log (n0)/$

Comment: Alright. But when I use log I get a different answer. that's what i am asking?

Comment: yes. how can i get to know which one I should use ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18886/discussion-between-vinayak-and-k170).